# C# Windows Forms Applications Hotkey - KeyDown event not working

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, hotkeys

I read a lot of questions about making a hotkey for a Windows Forms Applications and tried the code a lot people said it was working, but for me, somehow not.

Code:

```
void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.S)   
        {
          timer1.Stop();
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true; 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create global hotkeys manager for your form to be available for all controls in that form, you need to override the `Form.ProcessCmdKey()` method that catch all keys for all controls, instead of using the form key down event that works only when the background is focused and which can only happens when `ActiveControl` is `null`:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
  switch ( keyData )
  {
    case Keys.Control | Keys.S:
      timer1.Stop();
      return true;
  }
  return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Thus you can catch any key combination you need and return true if processed.